# background issue with my vim

Tags: vim, iterm, iterm2

How do I get rid of the gray-highlight in my vim editor? I am not selecting anything, this is what I see when I load VI.

Thank you.

image: http://postimg.org/image/xe7uw7nqt/

Comment: you'd better show your vimrc,and `set background=dark` will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your vimrc try setting..

```
highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
```

You can also test this from your vim session by pressing ":" and entering it. I believe your colorscheme's Normal color is off for terminals (maybe was a GUI based colorscheme?).

Comment: @DavidTrinh: I voted up for you :)
I think you don't need rep to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your color scheme, e.g.

```
:colorscheme morning
```